# Поиск элемента в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Код:

```
users = [12390312, 12313123, 57289234, 21837129398]

userstats = 21837129398

print("Начинаю поиск")
for element in users:
    if userstats == users:
        break
    else:
        print("'userstats' нет в списке 'users'")

print("'userstats' есть в списке 'users'")
```

К примеру в коде у меня есть список c id пользователей

```
users = [12390312, 12313123, 57289234, 21837129398]
```

И есть сервер который отправляет мне по команде id пользователя в переменную `userstats`.

Предположим он отправил мне переменную с id `21837129398`

В теории код должен найти в списке этот id, если находит, нужно чтобы выполнялся этот код: `print("'userstats' есть в списке 'users'")`
А если не находит нужно чтобы выполнялся этот код: `print("'userstats' нет в списке 'users'")`

Но с моим кодом у меня не выходит, не знаю что делать, пробовал гуглить, ничего не нагуглил. Я ещё новичок в этой сфере, может что-то не знаю, подскажите :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для таких проверок можно воспользоваться оператором `in`. Если элемент есть в коллекции, то вернётся `True`, иначе - `False`.

***Код:***

```py
users = [12390312, 12313123, 57289234, 21837129398]

userstats = 21837129398
if userstats in users:
    print("'userstats' есть в списке 'users'")
else:
    print("'userstats' нет в списке 'users'")
```

***stdout:***

```html
'userstats' есть в списке 'users'
```

**P. S.:**

Код можно сократить, используя аналог тернарного оператора:

```py
print("'userstats'", 'есть' if userstats in users else 'нет', "в списке 'users'")
```

Answer (score 4):

В случае бинарного ветвления можно воспользоваться индексированием при помощи булевого значения - `False == 0` / `True == 1`:

```
In [85]: verbs = ["нет", "есть"]

In [86]: print(f"'userstats' {verbs[userstats in users]} в списке 'users'")
'userstats' есть в списке 'users'
```

Answer (score 1):

Как сделать это правильно с помощью `in`, вам уже написали.

А вот почему не работает ваш код:

```
for element in users:
    if userstats == users:
        break
    else:
        print("'userstats' нет в списке 'users'")
```

Здесь у вас userstats - это один элемент. А users - это весь список. Очевидно, что условие `userstats == users` никогда не выполнится, т.к. один элемент не будет равен всему списку.

Вам нужно было вместо `userstats == users` написать `element == users`, вот тогда бы ваш код заработал.

Comment: Не думаю, что можно обойтись лишь этой правкой. Данный код будет печатать `'userstats' нет в списке 'users'` от `0` до `len(users)` раз. То есть, для правильной работы нужно блок `else` связывать с `for`, а сообщение о том, что элемент найден, вставить перед `break`. Тогда это будет работать, как предполагалось.

Comment: @nomnoms12, да вы правы, этот момент я не учёл. Но в любом случае правильнее всего это делать через in, а мой ответ призван просто объяснить, почему код автора работает так, как он работает.